# create Timers dynamically and identify which timer is raising the tick event

Tags: c#, timer

I am working in web application in which I need to create Timers dynamically based on number of records in database. I am able to do that but the problem is I can't identify which timer is raising the tick event.

Below is the sample code on which I am working:

```
Timer[] timers = new Timer[Wavcount];
for (int i=0;i<Wavcount;i++) {
    Timer t1 = new Timer();
    t1.Interval = 1000;
    t1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(SomeStaticMethod);
    t1.Start();
}

private static void SomeStaticMethod(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    Timer t1 = (Timer)sender;
    duration = duration + 1;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean you can't? you just did : `Timer t1 = (Timer)sender`

Comment: check it in t1 object

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core is making things easier, here you can provide an object to the elapsed/tick event like so:

```
    ...
    foreach(var serviceViewModel in ServiceViewModels)
    {
        var timer = new Timer(PollSource, serviceViewModel, 0, serviceViewModel.PollingInterval * 1000);
    }
}

private void PollSource(object stateInfo)
{
}
```

In "PollSource" you'll get your data as "stateInfo", in my case the view model which contains all the information I need in the callback.

Answer (score -1):

So, you need some *name* for each timer. Since the timer itself doesn't have anything that can be used, you could provide the desired information directly to the called function by wrapping the call in a lambda function:

```
Timer[] timers = new Timer[Wavcount];
for (int i=0; i < Wavcount; i++)
{
    Timer t1 = new Timer();
    t1.Interval = 1000;
    t1.Elapsed += (s, e) => SomeStaticMethod(s as Timer, e.SignalTime, "Timer " + i);
    t1.Start();
}

private static void SomeStaticMethod(Timer timer, DateTime signalTime, string timerName)
{
    Console.WriteLine(timerName + " fired at " + signalTime);
}
```